# Spring is not running my @Scheduled(cron = "0,30 * * * * *")

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, chron

- Following is code
- I am using spring.boot.version 1.4.1.RELEASE now
- Nothing is printed when I start the server
- I am using @Scheduled annotation to run a cron job but It never starts
- Same code works fine if I create new project and use following classes
- Please suggest what can possibly go wrong ?

  ```
              package com.equilar.bsp;
              import java.util.TimeZone;
              import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
              import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
              import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
              import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
              import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
              import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
              import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
              import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScan;
              import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
              import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
              import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
              import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;
              import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
              import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

              import com.amazonaws.http.IdleConnectionReaper;
              import com.cloudinary.Cloudinary;
              import com.equilar.bsp.config.RedisConfig;
              import com.equilar.bsp.config.SecurityConfig;
              import com.equilar.bsp.mvc.MvcConfig;
              import com.equilar.bsp.util.JwtTokenGenerator;
              import com.equilar.bsp.util.Util;


              @SpringBootApplication
              @EnableScheduling
              @Configuration
              @EnableAutoConfiguration
              @EnableJpaAuditing
              //@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.equilar" ,lazyInit = true)
              @EnableJpaRepositories("com.equilar")
              @EntityScan({"com.equilar.bsp.domain", "com.equilar.newcommon.folder.domain", "com.equilar.newcommon.pdf.domain"})




              public class Application  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

                  public static void main(String[] args) {
                      // set default timezone first thing!!
                      TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
                      JwtTokenGenerator.getStartTime();
                  }

                  @Override
                  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
                      return application.sources(applicationClass, SecurityConfig.class, MvcConfig.class, RedisConfig.class);
                  }

                  private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;

                  @PreDestroy
                  private void cleanUp() {
                     /* try {
                          // Shutting down AWS IdleConnectionReaper thread...
                          IdleConnectionReaper.shutdown();
                          List<Thread> threadsList = getThreadByName("logback-loggly-appender");
                          if(!Util.isNullOrEmptyCollection(threadsList)){
                              for (Thread  thread : threadsList) {
                                  thread.interrupt();
                              }
                          }

                      } catch (Throwable t) {
                          // log error
                          t.printStackTrace();
                      }*/
                  }

                  /*public List<Thread> getThreadByName(String threadName) {
                      List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
                      for (Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) {
                          if (t.getName().equals(threadName)){
                              threads.add(t);
                          }
                      }
                      return threads;
                  }*/

                  @Value("${CLOUDINARY_URL}")
                  private String cloudinaryUrl;

                  @Bean(name = "cloudinary")
                  public Cloudinary Instance() {
                      return new Cloudinary(cloudinaryUrl);
                  }
              }




          package com.equilar.bsp.calc;


          import org.slf4j.Logger;
          import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
          import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

          @org.springframework.stereotype.Component
          public class Component {

              private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());


              @Scheduled(
                      cron = "0,30 * * * * *")
              public void cronJob() {
                  logger.info("> cronJob");


                  logger.info("\n\n>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> In Chron Job."
                        );

                  logger.info(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ");
              }
          }
  ```

Comment: When you set a breakpoint in the `reportCurrentTime` method is that breakpoint reached when you start the application?

Comment: No, it never goes inside reportCurrentTime  method

Comment: how did you run the application?

Comment: I am running it as Spring Boot App and It's working now.I just restarted my STS.But same code doesn't work when I use it in my existing application.

Answer (score 1):

Your code sample looks totally fine for me. Moreover, I've created a project with sample code you've provided and it worked( with spring.boot.version 1.2.1.RELEASE ).

There is a similar project on [github](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-scheduling-tasks/tree/master/complete) you may be interested in.

Comment: I am running it as Spring Boot App and It's working now.I just restarted my STS.But same code doesn't work when I use it in my existing application.I updated my code.